# Where do they get the Jaeger strength measurement from in "Pacific Rim"?

Tags: pacific-rim

In the movie *Pacific Rim*, Crimson Typhoon is described as having "50 diesel engines per muscle strand" of strength.

Where did they get that from? Is that a complete fantasy measurement that they came up with to describe their strength? Something akin to Warp factor numbers in *Star Trek*?

[image: Jaeger schematics with measurements]

Comment: As a (multiple degree) engineer, you are barking up the wrong tree.  Humanoid robots of this size are terrible designs for engines of war.  Although a Bolo (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolo_%28tank%29) is still fantastical, it'd do a much better job and be a more realistic design for the job.

Pacific Rim is more of a fantasy in a sciency like future setting.

Comment: I dearly hope it is from the Jaegermonsters from Girl Genius.

Comment: Maybe try replacing the Bugatti Veyron motor with an actual diesel engine like the ones used in ships.

Comment: I'm with Jim2B. We need Bolo movies, clearly. I can get behind this. I will happily prepurchase tickets to a Bolo movie.

Comment: Diesel engines come in such broad sizes and power ratings as to be meaningless.  I would bet money the writer chose that deliberately to sound powerful without pinning themselves down to specifics.

Comment: how many muscle strands are used in each arm?  it's just a technobabble way of saying it's strong

Comment: This is missing the possibility of gearboxes, one engine could lift the arm, very slowly.

Answer (score 6):

I just did a quick Google search about the [biggest diesel engine](https://www.amusingplanet.com/2013/03/the-largest-and-most-powerful-diesel.html).

> Torque: 7,603,850 newton metres (5,608,310 lbf·ft) @ 102 rpm

and 5,600,000 lbf ft * 50 = 280,000,000 lbf ft making it seem possible to me that there might be smaller diesel engines with a torque of 1,631,232 lb ft = 2,211,653 Nm.

Comment: In contrast, the [Chevy Beat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevrolet_Spark#Beat_diesel) has a 1.0L 3 cylinder diesel with just 160 Nm of torque.  That gives the writers a comfortable four orders of magnitude wiggle room by describing power in terms of "diesel engines".

Comment: @Schwern unrelated but I freaking love the latest tech diesels and petrols out of Europe. French and Italian diesels like the multijet are cool and I have the British Ford 1.0T i3 'Fox' in my Fiesta B-Max. The very latest Fox has a combined starter/hybrid motor for 154hp and a flat 150 ish ft-lbs of torque.
It would not, however, even power a Jaeger toe.